# Prevent CSS underline animation when hovering over a specific link, while allowing it for other <a> elements

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-animations

I'm designing a site using a navbar template I made a while ago. When I made that template, there were no other links in the document, but now, since I'm using it in a full site, there are. When you hover over a normal link, the colour stays the same but a CSS underline animation plays out. This is also supposed to happen for the links in the navbar, except one — the title of the site. After adding the following to my CSS, the underline animation started playing out when hovering over the title (the `.link` is there now because I added a class of that name to all non-navbar links to try to fix it, alas to no avail):

```css
a.link {
  color: #5dc0e6;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.link:hover {
  color: #5dc0e6;
}

a.link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #5dc0e6;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a.link:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

I have no idea what to do at this point. As I said, I tried a class on all non-navbar links, but it didn't work. I'm completely at a loss. This is the CSS for the site title:

```css
ul.title {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 20;
      overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/12/05/06/technology-1587673_960_720.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
      background-color: #e6e5e6;
      font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      position: static;
}
```

Here is the entire HTML document (edited slightly to remove site info):

```html
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Home &mdash; Site Title</title>
        <link href="media/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
        <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo:500,700" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="title">
          <li><a class="link st" href="/"><font color="#e5e6e5">Site Title</font></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="nav-item" href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item" href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item" href="#">Sites</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>Welcome to my site! More will be available soon...<br>
        <em>Developed by <a class="link" href="#">Developer</a></em>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the title of the page is the only link that does not behave like the others; I think a simple solution would be to use a different class name for the title. Maybe `.title` then don't add the animation part to it;

```
a.link, a.title {
  color: #5dc0e6;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.link:hover, a.title {
  color: #5dc0e6;
}

a.link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #5dc0e6;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a.link:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is something I've already tried - sorry if I didn't make it clear in my question. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

I added a snippet to illustrate what I think you're looking for. :)

```css
a:not(.nope) {
  color: #5dc0e6;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:not(.nope):hover {
  color: #5dc0e6;
}

a.nope {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:not(.nope):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #5dc0e6;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:not(.nope):hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

ul.title {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 20;
      overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/12/05/06/technology-1587673_960_720.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
      background-color: #e6e5e6;
      font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      position: static;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul a:not(.nope) {

}
```

```html
<ul class="title">
          <li><a class="link nope" href="/"><font color="#e5e6e5">Site Title</font></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="nav-item" href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item" href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item" href="#">Sites</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>Welcome to my site! More will be available soon...<br>
        <em>Developed by <a class="link" href="#">Developer</a></em>.</p>
```

You're looking for `:not()` in css. Just add a custom class to the one link, and in your link styling, append `:not(.custom-link)` in the `a` styling. If you provide the HTML, I can show you how by editing my answer. :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me, any idea why? I thought it might be to do with the fact that the title's styles were defined in the CSS as ul rather than li, but I tried changing it, alas to no avail. I'll edit my answer and add the HTML (I renamed the `nope` class to `st` for `static` (as in no animation) in case you're confused).

Comment: Which links are special and which is regular? The li links are the animated, and the dev one isn't, correct?

Comment: Also - Why are you using two `<ul>` elements next to each other? You can also use `:first-child` to apply styling to the first element that matches whatever selector prefixes that selector

Comment: I've edited the snippet to do what I think you want it to do. You still had `.link` tags on anchor elements that didn't have the `.link` class anymore. Let me know if that does it!

Comment: Both the Developer link and the `li` links are animated. It's just the Site Title link which isn't supposed to be. I'll try out your snippet, thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay, I don't know what's going on, but for some reason that's not working either. Maybe I'm putting the code in wrong, I couldn't think how though. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is my snippet your intended behavior?